# cant able to connect to flash in nodejs

Tags: flash, node.js

I cant able to enter in `onConnect` function in nodeJS. All the thing is i am trying to connect to flash using nodejs as server.

my server.js is

```
 var net = require('net');

 var mySocket;

 var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
   mySocket = socket;
   mySocket.on("connect", onConnect);
   mySocket.on("data", onData);
 });

 function onConnect()
 {
    console.log("Connected to Flash");
 }

 function onData(d)
 {
   if(d == "exit\0")
   {
      console.log("exit");
      mySocket.end();
      server.close();
    }
   else
   {
           console.log("From Flash = " + d);
            mySocket.write(d, 'utf8');
    }
 }

  server.listen(9001, "127.0.0.1");
  console.log("Connection Established");
```

could any one tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: You might need to include your client-side code as well in order to see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Event `connection` is for class net.Server (the server) and `connect` is for class net.Socket (the client). When you create a server via net.createServer, the function you pass is automatically set as listener for `connection` event. From the [API doc](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) -

> **net.createServer([options], [connectionListener])**
>
> Creates a new TCP server. The connectionListener argument is
>   automatically set as a listener for the 'connection' event.

The server has no `connect` event. To use `connect` create another create another `client.js` with following and execute it after running your `server.js` .

```
 var net = require('net');
 var port = 9001,
     host = '127.0.0.1';
 var socket = net.createConnection(port, host);
 console.log('Socket created.');
 socket.on('data', function (data) {
     console.log('RESPONSE: ' + data);
 }).on('connect', function () {
     socket.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
 }).on('end', function () {
     console.log('DONE');
 });
```